# Spring boot template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, templates, spring-boot

Error resolving template "producaoPrimaria", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I got this erros when i try to access this tamplate

i using angularJs in my front-end the method that call template is this

```
$scope.saude = function(idSistemaSelecionado) {

        idEntidadeSelecionada = $location.$$search.dataBase;

        $q.when();  

        if(idSistemaSelecionado ==502){
            location.href = "arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimaria?dataBase=" + idEntidadeSelecionada + "&app=" + idSistemaSelecionado;
        }   

    };
```

and my appController

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$qProvider){
     $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

$routeProvider
.when("/producaoPrimaria", {templateUrl:'/arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimariaPaginas/inicioPp.html',  controller:'inicioPpController'})

}
```

[image]

and my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimaria")
    public String irParaProducaoPrimaria(){

        return "producaoPrimaria";
    }
```

what i did wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to return full path to the template file relative to the templates folder. Try something like this:

```java
@RequestMapping("/arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimaria")
public String irParaProducaoPrimaria() {

    return "arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimaria";
}
```